Error on Validating data received via the Mini App in php?
function hmac_sha256($key, $data) {
    return hash_hmac('sha256', $data, $key, true);
}

function validate_telegram_data($received_data) {
    
    global $bot_token;
    parse_str($received_data, $data);
    ksort($data);
    $received_hash = $data['hash'];
    
    unset($data['hash']);
    $data_check_string = '';
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $data_check_string .= $key . '=' . $value . "\n";
    }
    
    // print_r($data_check_string);
    $secret_key = hmac_sha256($bot_token, "WebAppData");
    $computed_hash = bin2hex(hmac_sha256($secret_key, $data_check_string));
    
    // print_r([$received_hash, $computed_hash]);
    
    if (hash_equals($computed_hash, $received_hash)) {
        if (isset($data['auth_date']) && (time() - intval($data['auth_date'])) < 86400) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

this is not working whyy??
validate_telegram_data('query_id=AAGohX8eAwAAAKiFfx7ierlk&user=%7B%22id%22%3A6954124712%2C%22first_name%22%3A%22Socilizer%20Support%22%2C%22last_name%22%3A%22%22%2C%22username%22%3A%22socilizer_support%22%2C%22language_code%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22allows_write_to_pm%22%3Atrue%7D&auth_date=1725191023&hash=1540cf7e36ebbadfe7faea9f20ccc68431cb24e1d106f860d27a560309f1ca3b');  // false why??

i am using same bot toekn and all is ok but giving defrent
Array
(
[0] => 1540cf7e36ebbadfe7faea9f20ccc68431cb24e1d106f860d27a560309f1ca3b // received_hash
[1] => 493b5e631f8aae6061e9079b961506c07f61a3fb4b31810ad26b01b9b1cfaadb // computed_hash
)
check..

The issue in the way the data_check_string is being using
The string concatenation in your code adds a new character "\n", Base on Telegram's documentation, the data_check_string should not include any additional newline characters.
Please check this code
function hmac_sha256($key, $data) {
    return hash_hmac('sha256', $data, $key, true);
}

function validate_telegram_data($received_data) {
    global $bot_token;
    parse_str($received_data, $data);
    ksort($data);
    $received_hash = $data['hash'];
    
    unset($data['hash']);
    $data_check_string = '';
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $data_check_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
    }
    // Remove the trailing '&'
    $data_check_string = rtrim($data_check_string, '&');
    
    $secret_key = hmac_sha256($bot_token, "WebAppData");
    $computed_hash = bin2hex(hmac_sha256($secret_key, $data_check_string));
    
    if (hash_equals($computed_hash, $received_hash)) {
        if (isset($data['auth_date']) && (time() - intval($data['auth_date'])) < 86400) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Example usage:
$bot_token = 'your-bot-token-here';
$result = validate_telegram_data('query_id=AAGohX8eAwAAAKiFfx7ierlk&user=%7B%22id%22%3A6954124712%2C%22first_name%22%3A%22Socilizer%20Support%22%2C%22last_name%22%3A%22%22%2C%22username%22%3A%22socilizer_support%22%2C%22language_code%22%3A%22en%22%2C%22allows_write_to_pm%22%3Atrue%7D&auth_date=1725191023&hash=1540cf7e36ebbadfe7faea9f20ccc68431cb24e1d106f860d27a560309f1ca3b');
var_dump($result); // Should return true if everything is correct


https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#validating-data-received-via-the-mini-app
check this broohh
